# Blazor using Serilog: ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: ConnectionStrings'

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, serilog

I like to implement log data from client (WASM) into a backend file using Serilog as [descripted here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/log-data-into-file-using-serilog-framework-in-blazor-server-app/).
At my program.cs (server app) I got already that:

```
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
        #if RELEASE
                webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
        #endif
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
```

When I add the code for Serilog...:

```
            .UseSerilog().ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
```

... I get the exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: ConnectionStrings'

The reason is because Startup is called two times and the config data are written two times and so the keys are already been added.

**Do you know a way to solve this problem?**
How I should manipulate the *UseSerilog().ConfigureWebHostDefaults()*?
Can I just delete one of both *webBuilder.UseStartup();*?
(Existing logic should remain and Serilog should be added).

Comment: Don't call `webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();` twice.

Comment: The problem isn't `UseStartup`. It's calling `.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>` twice, which tries to set up the host *and the configuration settings* twice. Remove `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` after `UseSerilog()`.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/53009

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the snippet :

```
.UseSerilog().ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
```

Just call `UseSerilog()`. The host was already configured earlier in :

```
 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
```

`ConfigureWebHostDefaults` as the name says configures the Host with its default DI, configuration and logging settings. Calling it twice would be a mistake no matter what - if the defaults were applied without error, `Serilog` would be removed from the pipeline. In this case, the same configuration settings are added to the Configuration dictionary, resulting in an exception.

If you want to call `UseSerilog` before `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`, actually place the call before it.

This is a snippet from my own hosted Blazor WASM project. `Logging.ConfigureSerilog` configures Serilog to log to files and a database table. `Environment.OSVersion.Platform` is used because at some point I developed the project on Mac and what to deploy on Windows, so I needed a way to specify Mac-specific settings

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog(Logging.ConfigureSerilog)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
            var os = Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
            config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.{os}.json", true);
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```